# Behaviour of OpenerView inside a loop

Tags: dialog-window

OpenerView works as expected in this:

```
OpenerView[{"This is the question", "This is the answer"}, False],
```

Yet when I put it in a loop, it has no effect:

```
Do[Print["hello"]; 
OpenerView[{"This is the question", "This is the answer"}, False], 3]
```

The "hello" prints fine, three times.

All I'm seeking to do is to

- print "This is the question" on the screen (1), so that
- the user needs to click to show "This is the answer" (2), and then
- they get a button saying "Next question" (3), and
- repeat (4).

The only input I need from the user is mouse clicks: to show each answer, and then once they've read it to move on to the next question.

1-2 can be got in isolation using OpenerView.

3 can be got with

```
ChoiceDialog["Next question", Modal -> True];
```

which works great in for example

```
Print["hello"];
ChoiceDialog["Next question", Modal -> True];
Print["world"];
```

But I can't get OpenerView to work in a loop so something like the following also fails to give the required output:

```
 Do[Print["hello ", i];
 ChoiceDialog["Next question", Modal -> False];
 Print["world"];
 OpenerView[{"This is the question", "This is the answer"}, False], 3]
```

I'd be grateful in advance for any help with this. I'm trying to keep it as simple as possible, but there must be something I don't understand with the functioning of OpenerView.

Comment: Look at [`CellPrint`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/CellPrint.html). Namely, you have to do `CellPrint[OpenerView[...]]`.

Comment: Or even just `Print[OpenerView[...]]`.

Comment: Notice that from Do's documentation: "Unless an explicit Return is used, the value returned by Do is Null." Most likely you want to use `Table` instead of `Do`, and then use something like `Column` to make it look nice. If you are generating a large number of OpenerViews, then I would use `CellPrint`.